# How to convert hair into a mesh

Tags: objects

This is my first time doing a character. What is the best way for me to convert the curves from which I made the hair into a mesh so that the mesh is not heavy? Please advise me something, I can't find any information about this at all.
[image]

[image]

Comment: RMB > Convert to > Mesh?

Comment: In this case, the grid will be very dense. Is there any better way?

Comment: Before converting, make sure that the resolution of your curves and profile curves is low

Comment: moonboots, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert to mesh, duplicate your curves and right click > *Convert To > Mesh*. If the result is too high in polygons, before converting, make sure that the resolution of your curves (main curve and profile) are low enough, make some tests until you're satisfied:

[image]